# How to compare two zip files with non *.zip extension in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, compare, zip, diff, file-association

Eclipse has native support to compare two zip files with each other. But this seems only to work if the file extension is *.zip. Is there a setting in Eclipse to enable this for more file extensions?

The zip format is used as container format for many different files. For example for office documents. A zip diff viewer can be very helpful here.

Comment: Probably done with the `org.eclipse.compare.structureCreators` extension point, in which case you could only do it with a plug-in.

Comment: This means I need a plugin for it? Are there some available?